# PHP checking function output

Tags: php, image-processing, resize

I have a basic function to resize image given below:

```
function resize() {

.....
...
..

imagejpeg($image_new,$img_path,80);

imagedestroy($image_old);
imagedestroy($image_new);
}
```

I need to call it in another function and see its output. How can i do that? I want something like:

```
function test(){
//calling resize function
if (resize() === true){ 
    echo "Success";
    } else {
    echo "resized failed"; 
    }
}
```

What I'm not understanding is that the resize function simply creates the image and detroys the older image files. How it will return the output that it was successful or not? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written your `resize` function is not returning information on whether it succeeds or fails and, furthermore, it always destroys both images (the two `imagedestroy` calls).  You'll need to rewrite the function to take account of the return codes from `imagedestroy` and `imagejpeg`.  The [documentation for the latter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) indicates that that function will return a boolean indicating whether it was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

`imagejpeg()` returns a boolean `FALSE` on failure (according to the [API](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php); collect its return and use that as the return of your `resize()` function:

```
function resize () {
  ...
  $success = imagejpeg($image_new, $img_path, 80);
  ...
  return $success
}
```

Also, you should probably be passing in the image as a parameter to `resize()`... it looks like you have a few global variables, which isn't [good](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable)(1) [practise](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)(2)